# Running React.JS Production Application on CentOS server with forever

Tags: reactjs, npm, deployment, centos, serve

Currently I'm working on a website, I've finished most of the site and would like to deploy a production version.

My issue is the following: 
I cannot seem to find a way to run "serve" with forever. I need to use serve to host the site as the site is a single page application, I've tried using the base files from the "/build" folder, however that doesn't build the site correctly.

Running the site with serve -s build works, but there's no way to keep the site running once the terminal has closed.

I am using a CentOS server.

Comment: use https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2

Comment: @HarishSoni My understanding of pm2 is you have to run a .js file with it? I'm trying to run "serve"

Comment: You can write a js file which will internally execute `npm start` in the directory it will solve the problem

Comment: @HarishSoni that won't work. npm start only runs in development mode